# Upgrading from 2.2.6 to 2.2.7

Tags: magento2.2.6, magento2.2.7

I just don't get this damn error and it's driving me crazy.

Problem 1
    - The requested package magento/product-enterprise-edition 2.2.7 exists as magento/product-enterprise-edition[2.2.6] but these are rejected by your constraint.

All i'm trying to do is upgrade from 2.2.6 to 2.2.7

Here is my composer.json file and when i first opened it up it said version 2.2.5 and the require was magento/product-enterprise-edition": "2.2.6",

```
{
    "name": "magento/project-enterprise-edition",
    "description": "eCommerce Platform for Growth (Enterprise Edition)",
    "type": "project",
    "version": "2.2.7",
    "license": [
        "proprietary"
    ],
    "require": {
        "magento/product-enterprise-edition": "2.2.7",
        "composer/composer": "@alpha",
        "magemojo/m2-ce-cron": "^1.2",
        "gene/bluefoot": "^1.0",
        "mageworx/module-advancedproductoptions": "2.15.0",
        "amasty/shopby": "^2.10",
        "amasty/feed": "^2.2",
        "amasty/smtp": "^1.1",
        "mageworx/module-downloads": "^2.5",
        "mageworx/module-seosuiteultimate": "^2.21",
        "mageworx/module-shippingrules": "^2.5",
        "mageworx/module-geoip": "^2.1",
        "amasty/module-page-speed-optimizer": "^1.0",
        "amasty/module-elastic-search": "^1.4"
    },
    "replace": {
        "amzn/amazon-pay-sdk-php": "*",
        "amzn/amazon-pay-and-login-with-amazon-core-module": "*",
        "amzn/login-with-amazon-module": "*",
        "amzn/amazon-pay-module": "*"
    },
    "require-dev": {
        "phpunit/phpunit": "~6.2.0",
        "squizlabs/php_codesniffer": "3.2.2",
        "phpmd/phpmd": "@stable",
        "pdepend/pdepend": "2.5.2",
        "friendsofphp/php-cs-fixer": "~2.2.1",
        "lusitanian/oauth": "~0.8.10",
        "sebastian/phpcpd": "2.0.4"
    },
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "Magento\\Framework\\": "lib/internal/Magento/Framework/",
            "Magento\\Setup\\": "setup/src/Magento/Setup/",
            "Magento\\": "app/code/Magento/"
        },
        "psr-0": {
            "": [
                "app/code/"
            ]
        },
        "files": [
            "app/etc/NonComposerComponentRegistration.php"
        ],
        "exclude-from-classmap": [
            "**/dev/**",
            "**/update/**",
            "**/Test/**"
        ]
    },
    "autoload-dev": {
        "psr-4": {
            "Magento\\Sniffs\\": "dev/tests/static/framework/Magento/Sniffs/",
            "Magento\\Tools\\": "dev/tools/Magento/Tools/",
            "Magento\\Tools\\Sanity\\": "dev/build/publication/sanity/Magento/Tools/Sanity/",
            "Magento\\TestFramework\\Inspection\\": "dev/tests/static/framework/Magento/TestFramework/Inspection/",
            "Magento\\TestFramework\\Utility\\": "dev/tests/static/framework/Magento/TestFramework/Utility/",
            "Magento\\ToolkitFramework\\": "dev/tools/performance-toolkit/framework/Magento/ToolkitFramework/"
        }
    },
    "minimum-stability": "stable",
    "repositories": {
        "0": {
            "type": "composer",
            "url": "https://repo.magento.com/"
        },
        "mageworx_packages": {
            "type": "composer",
            "url": "https://packages.mageworx.com/"
        },
        "amasty": {
            "type": "composer",
            "url": "https://composer.amasty.com/enterprise/"
        },
        "xtento": {
            "type": "composer",
            "url": "https://repo.xtento.com"
        },
        "mirasvit-ssu2": {
            "type": "composer",
            "url": "https://34628:AB94VE15JD@packages.mirasvit.com/"
        },
        "firebear": {
            "type": "composer",
            "url": "https://firebearstudio.com/composer/download/package/type/ee/user/c039b63f7e733ff958729ef4803c06b0/password/ded1d044e9cf2c78c3be7c37fce9a77d/"
        }
    },
    "extra": {
        "magento-force": "override"
    }
}
```